# Transfer value from cell to ComboBox avoiding triggering said ComboBox change

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Basically that's my question. I have comboBoxes that affect other ComboBoxes on change and that's all perfect, but I have a need to be able to get the value back from cell to ComboBox on a separate Excel file open and like iI have it written now - it triggers change ComboBox and affects other ComboBoxes which now will be empty and that's bad. What I basically need is to maintain selected items in ComboBoxes once opening the saved workbook once again.

The way I have it written from ComboBox to Sheet:

```
'Paste value to sheet
Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range("C4").Value = UserForm_TVPM.Language_ComboBox.Text
```

And the way I get it loaded back to ComboBox from sheet:

```
UserForm_TVPM.Language_ComboBox.Value = Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range("C4").Value
```

Same issue occurs upon unloading and showing the UserForm. SInce I have to populate the now empty ComboBoxes.

Could someone, help me solve this problem, please?

P.S.

I have a module that has many subroutines with load functions such as provided in the original post for each userform. That's how I get the value from cell to combobox. AND I have a userform initialize subroutine that mostly has additem function for all the comboboxes in said userform. Later on while user is working with the file - all is fine as I can hide userforms without losing the date in it's combopboxes, BUT upon unloading the userform in any way (weather closing the workbook or simply going to another userform that unloads the previous) the data will be lost and on next initialize of the userform will be loaded back in. Because I have comboboxes that items are dependant on selection in some other combobox - in this scenario I lose the calculated value in userform AND in worksheet.

My understanding is that it happens because upon loading the userform, it's all blank, and upon loading the values it triggers each combobox change event causing some dependant combobox items to be cleared recalculated to provide a correct range of options to select from, and that in turn deletes the dependant comboboxes value in the worksheet because of the transferring combobox value to worksheet. So I generally need to maintain all the combobox values as they were sent to worksheet upon loading a userform, much like it would be if I were to hide a userform and then show it again. :)

Comment: Did you try Application.EnableEvents? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure If I used it correctly. I basically disabled it in change sub and after all teh functions enabled it and it didn't have any effect

Comment: @АлексейР somehow `Application.EnableEvents` does not disable events from user forms and its controls but only events from the worksheets.

Comment: In taht case I don't understand the concept of it at all. It's not only about saving... it's the same upon unloading and showing the now blank UserForm taht now has to be populated with values from Worksheet

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `ControlSource` of the ComboBox to your cell. So it always shows the same value as the cell and you don't need to paste it from the ComboBox to the cell and vice versa.

```
UserForm_TVPM.Language_ComboBox.ControlSource = "'Machine Specification'!C4"
```

Or set the `ControlSource` in the propery window of the combo box.

The only other idea I have is to have a global variable as switch.

```
Option Explicit

Private SkipChangeEvent As Boolean

Private Sub Language_ComboBox_Change()
    If SkipChangeEvent Then Exit Sub
    
    'your code here
End Sub

Public Sub Example()
    SkipChangeEvent = True   'disable change event
    UserForm_TVPM.Language_ComboBox.Value = Worksheets("Machine Specification").Range("C4").Value
    SkipChangeEvent = False  'enable change event
End Sub
```

But I would prefer the first solution.

---

According comments I propose another solution:

In every userform you want to use that put on top:

```
Option Explicit

Private IsInitialized As Boolean 'this is false by default and false after every unload too.
```

This has to be private and every userform needs its own variable declaration otherwise it does not work with multiple userforms.

In your change events do

```
Private Sub Language_ComboBox_Change()
    If Not IsInitialized Then Exit Sub ' events don't run until you tell the userform IsInitialized is true.
    
    'your code here
End Sub
```

Where ever you have your code to initialize the values of your combo boxes put the following after initialization is finished:

```
IsInitialized = True
```

Comment: ControlSource is teh first thing I tried and it didn't work well with interconnected ComboBoxes where one ComboBox items list is calculated from another AND dynamically updates the worksheet. It basically was teh most undesired solution in terms of result

Comment: @Eduards well then you can only try the second solution I suggested, to turn the event off while changing the value.

Comment: Alright. I'm a little confused of where to put the option explicit and taht private boolean since obviously my UserForm conists of more than one ComboBox

Comment: `Option Explicit` is to force VBA to declare **all** variabels before usage. This is a very good practice and you should have this line as first line in **every** module and code (see [here](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) and do some research on it for more info). The `Private SkipChangeEvent As Boolean` then goes right below the `Option Explicit` before any `Sub` or `Function`. This is declaring a global variable that can be used in every `Sub` or `Function` of the module/userform where you declared it (do some research on global variables).

Comment: It has no effect at all, unfortunately. I  added SkipChangeEvent = True to a module that loads sheet values to combo box and then disabled it after loading all the values. And on each combobox change event I did     If SkipChangeEvent Then Exit Sub

Comment: What has no effect? Please be more precise. We cannot help without information. This denfinitely works if you do it properly. You can edit your question to show what you did.

Comment: I have no information, mate! I explained what I did and it had no visible effect

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` in every module/userform/worksheet as first line? If not make sure you use it, otherwise you might generate multiple variables with the same name without knowing! Also note that `Private SkipChangeEvent As Boolean` declares the variable only in that userform where that code is. So you can use the `SkipChangeEvent` variable **only** in that userform and in no other modules!

Comment: That means if I change it to "Public" - it will work in all other modules. Am I right?

Comment: @Eduards No you cannot have public variables in userforms. If you want to be able to use it in any module it has do be declared as `Public` in a **module** instead of the userform.

Comment: In that case I don't understand the logic of it at all. However I provided an additional info in the original post. I explained the problem in more detail and provided my assumed cause of the issue

Comment: If only initialization is your issue then see my edited answer and my additional proposal.

Comment: Thanks! What happens now is that no comboBox value gets sent to worksheet no more which is obviously NOT what I am looking for. I suppose it's because it still has to go to the additem section of teh combobox which is located in current userform_initialize subroutine

Comment: Well you asked to prevent the change events from running during initializing the combo boxes (until `IsInitialized = True`) that is what I have answered. If you have a new problem with a new question you should ask a new question and explain properly what the issue is.

Comment: I still have the same problem and question "How to transfer value from cell to ComboBox avoiding triggering said ComboBox change event?"

Comment: I answered that. With my last proposal in my answer, the change event won't trigger until you set `IsInitialized = True`. So transfer your values before setting `IsInitialized = True` and it will not trigger the events. Once you set `IsInitialized = True` the change event will trigger again. That is the exact answer to that question. The example I showed will work exactly like that.

Comment: Alright but the result is still the same as it was without it. Possibly it has to do with setting it true at the end of the initialize subroutine?

Comment: Then go through your code step by step using F8 when loading the userform to see when the events get triggered. So you can see which line gets excecuted after another. You need to do some debugging to find out what triggers them.

Comment: I assume that the solution is correct but I can't get it to work properly. I mean It does now load all the values to userform BUT once I manually change the values in comboboxes, the full functionality of the dependant comboboxes does not work fully. For example, it does recalculate the items to give BUT does not clear the items elected prior to calculation where it did taht before (cleared items list and value in combobox)